# how to download youtube videos without any software or extension?

Tags: video, google-chrome, flash, youtube, mozilla

I am trying to download youtube video and I find several software and extension which can done the job, but I was wondering is it possible to download youtube video without any software and extension while streaming the video using web browser. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, thank you in advance.

Comment: Extensions are the way to go.  What is your objection to using them? I suspect I may have a workaround for you if you can explain your reasoning.

Comment: I do not know is it ok to use software to download those video and i am confused how much safe it would be to use extension, thats the reason I asked for another way of download.

Comment: Try this link : [ClipConveter](http://www.clipconverter.cc/); This site will allow you to download YouTube video with support of converting it into any other format too.

Comment: Are you still waiting for an answer? or you have satisfied with the solution Novice provided?

Comment: I was wanted to download video without any software or extension and without depending on hosting site. it would be great just watch the video and if I like it, make a copy of it. I was asking because when we stream a video it must save it some where in the hard disk, and if I can make a copy of it I do not have to depend on software or extension.

Comment: I've used several extensions to download certain youtube videos I felt were important to preserve... for whatever reason.  They have all worked.  Some were easier to use.  Not once have I ever wondered if it was safe, and nothing ever happened to suggest to me that what I had done was unsafe.  If there's some specific aspect of safety you are concerned about, please tell us.

Comment: I'd go with @Novice, as it is the easiest way to download it no streaming while doing so. But this is safe as the site **ClipConverter** itself does all what is required and just gives you only the options to download

Answer (score 1):

To download youtube videos without software extensions is possible, seeing as we are using ubuntu and thus have `perl` preinstalled and the great `wget` at our disposal.
There is a Perl script at [Calomel's site](https://calomel.org/youtube_wget.html) that I use for this purpose, which extracts the path of the video file and passes this path as a parameter to `wget`.
If you haven't got wget installed (I doubt that you haven't), you can install it from the repositories.As is described on the site, you just start the script with the url of the site in which the video is.I am aware that some people don't like the terminal (which is sad),so therefore I wrote a little perl script for you.But it's dependant of the  perl Tk library, so if you want to use it, you'll have to install `perl-tk`

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#Script to collect input for calomels perl script to download youtube videos
use Tk;
my @LIST = ();
if (@ARGV) {
    @LIST = @ARGV;
    &downloadList();
    &endProg();
}
my $UserInput = undef;
my $infoText = 'This Script is dependant of wget and Tk';
our $testBlub = 0;

our $mw = MainWindow->new(-title => 'Youtube Downloader Beta');
$mw -> geometry("350x300");
$mw->Label(-text =>'Insert Youtube Link with Copy&Paste')->pack;
my $message = $mw->Entry(-width  => 50,-textvariable => \$UserInput);
$message->pack(-side=>'top');
my $Button1 = $mw->Button(-text => 'Add entry to list',-command => \&addList)->pack;
my $Button2 = $mw->Button(-text => 'Start Downloading',-command => \&downloadList)->pack;
my $exitButton = $mw->Button(-text => 'Exit',-command => \&endProg)->pack;
my $infoBoard = $mw->Label(-text => $infoText) ->pack;
our $ListBoard = $mw->Label(-text => $testBlub )->pack;
$mw ->update;


MainLoop;

sub addList {
    push(@LIST,$UserInput . "\n");
    $testBlub = $testBlub . $UserInput . "\n";
    $ListBoard -> configure(-text => $testBlub);
    $mw -> update;
}

sub downloadList {
    print "Event Download catched!\n";
    for my $test (@LIST) {
        print $test;
    }
    for my $Item (@LIST) {
        `./youtube_wget.pl $Item`;
        print "$Item is done\n";
    }
    @LIST = ();
}

sub endProg {
    exit(0);
}
```

You can then just make a launcher for it that you can click on to start the script.
Well anyway, I hope this helps solving your problem.Last thing I'd like to say, the code above is not the most elegant solution, it just does what it should.